# A way to hide data from multiple unrelated tables using CriteriaAPI

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, criteria, criteria-api

I have a task when I have to hide some rows from tables by record existence / not existence record row from filter table.

What I mean. For example I have a few tables:

company, contact, address, filter

And I have to select from company table data that match some condition from filter table. I guess to use something like

filter_table_name (or Entity class name)
filter_field_name (or Entity field name)
filter_field_type (or Java type)
filter_field_value (for sorting)

and somehow add to join or sub select in main query, but I don't know how.

What is the best way to do this? I'm using Spring Data JPA.